# You mean besides ninjas? Recent insightful comments

Tags: discussion, comments, data-explorer

I made you a list of [recent insightful comments](http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/487). I'm really enjoying reading through it and it's almost Friday anyway.

Comment: note, the user names and titles are links. the same query can be ran on meta and the rest of the sites. And what is the deal with that syntax highlighting?

Comment: I would just like to say thank you. I may never get back to work now. :)

Comment: This would be awesome as an RSS feed. Imagine getting 20 new insightful comments to read every morning...

Comment: Just tweaked the query to see if I was anywhere near the pundit badge and with only 2 comments with 10 or more votes the answer is a resounding "NO!" :(